# Does the winner of the election become king immediately?

Tags: joukamachi-no-dandelion

Does the winner of the election become king immediately? Or do they merely become heir apparent, to succeed Souichirou when he retires/dies?

I ask, because in episode 12,

> we learn that Shuu has won the election. Was the ceremony at the end of episode 12 a proper coronation for him? Or was it just a "congratulations, you're the heir, now wait a few decades" type of thing? From the way Souichirou spoke to him, I couldn't quite tell which it was.